# Marginalization over the nuisance variable

Tags: bayesian, gaussian-process, joint-distribution, conditional

I was reading a paper in which they state
$$ \text{P}(\mathbf{y}, \mathbf{f}, \mathbf{u}) =  \text{P}(\mathbf{y}| \mathbf{f})\text{P}(\mathbf{f}| \mathbf{u})\text{P}(\mathbf{u})$$
With $\mathbf{f}$ being conditionally independent to $\mathbf{y}$ given $\mathbf{u}$. They state the following equation to marginalize $\mathbf{u}$ to obtain the posterior for $\mathbf{f}$.
$$ \text{P}(\mathbf{f}| \mathbf{y}) = \int \text{P}(\mathbf{f}| \mathbf{u})\text{P}(\mathbf{u}| \mathbf{y})d\mathbf{u}$$

1. How did they get from the joint to the marginal over $\mathbf{u}$?
2. In the general case where there are no independence or conditional independence, since $\text{P}(\mathbf{y}, \mathbf{f}, \mathbf{u})$ has 3 different expressions based on the chain rule, how would i go about in choosing the 1 of the 3 expressions in a way that i wanted to marginalize out $\mathbf{u}$

EDIT:
Thanks all , I think its more like I havent provided enough context rather than a typo? (I took the equations as is from the following referenced papers) so basically the paper is from https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.08933.pdf (Eq 1) which has to do with Deep Gaussian Processes (although in this case its explaining a single layer GP which is analogous to a sparse GP i.e. a standard GP with an additional (output) variable $\mathbf{u}$). What they wrote is : $$ \text{p}(\mathbf{y}, \mathbf{f}, \mathbf{u}) =\text{p}(\mathbf{f}| \mathbf{u})\text{p}(\mathbf{u}) \prod_{i=1}^{N}\, \text{P}(y_i| f_i)$$ Where the product of the first two terms of the RHS is the GP prior and the last term the likelihood
In another paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.05490.pdf), which is a continuation of the former, describes the same formula as
$$ \text{p}(\mathbf{y}, \mathbf{f}, \mathbf{u}) =  \text{p}(\mathbf{y}| \mathbf{f})\text{p}(\mathbf{f}| \mathbf{u})\text{p}(\mathbf{u})$$
Exactly as i have written it previously.

Comment: Do you have a typo in the very first equation, on the RHS?   Should the first term be p(y|u)?

Comment: (1) & (2) This is an identity called Chapman-Kolmogorov [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chapman–Kolmogorov_equation), [mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Chapman-KolmogorovEquation.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the joint density $P(y,f,u)$ and you know that $f\perp y | u$, then you can rewrite the joint as

$$P(y,f,u)=P(y,f|u)P(u)=P(y|u)P(f|u)P(u) \ \ (1)$$

Then for calculating to the marginal $P(f,y)$ over $u$ you calculate

$$P(f|y)=\int P(f,u|y)du = \int \frac{P(f,u,y)}{P(y)}du$$

now using the decomposition of the joint distribution  $(1)$ you have that

$$= \int \frac{P(y|u)P(f|u)P(u)}{P(y)}du$$

I don't really know which other expressions you refer to, but in the cases where you do not have any kind of independence the you would calculate the $P(f|y)$ as

$$P(f|y) = \int P(f,u|y)du=\int \frac{P(f,u,y)}{P(y)}du = \int \frac{P(f|u,y)P(u,y)}{P(y)}du=\int\frac{P(f|u,y)P(u|y)P(y)}{P(y)}du$$

$$=\int P(f|u,y)P(u|y)du$$

Comment: (+1) for detailed explanations.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments, the first multiplicand should be $p(y|u)$ because it's originally $p(y|f,u)$ and it's stated that $y$ and $f$ are conditionally independent given $u$.

1. For the integral, you have
   $$p(f|y)=\int p(f,u|y)du=\int \underbrace{p(f|y,u)}_{p(f|u)}p(u|y)du$$
2. Based on what you calculate, you'll include the term $u$ in the three-term expression and integrate over it, just as in the middle part above.

Comment: Nice explanation, but original post states `In the general case where there are no independence or conditional independence`.

Comment: @MehmetSuzen thanks for your comment! That assumption is for the second part and I believe I addressed it in (2). But, just to reiterate for the OP, in general case, the equation given in the beginning doesn't hold.

Comment: Thank you for the response, Got it  it was for the (2) part.

Comment: Thanks @gunes , I made an edit in the original post. Basically, i took the equations exactly as is in the paper. So im not sure about a typo :/, maybe more like i havent provided enough context to the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Though, there were great answers, specially from @gunes.

The most generic case where there is no independence or conditional independence assumption, marginalising $\mathbf{f}$, over $\mathbf{u}$ given $\mathbf{y}$ forms a Markovian chain, $\mathbf{f} \rightarrow  \mathbf{u} \rightarrow \mathbf{y}$, and expressed as [Chapman-Kolmogorov Equation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Chapman-KolmogorovEquation.html) (CKE), or identity. This is exactly what authors written,

$$ \text{P}(\mathbf{f}| \mathbf{y}) = \int \text{P}(\mathbf{f}| \mathbf{u})\text{P}(\mathbf{u}| \mathbf{y})d\mathbf{u} $$

This relationship is a CKE. Each conditional probability is a transition density in Markovian sense for the transitions. The variable $\mathbf{u}$ plays a role of  [nuisance variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuisance_variable) that we marginalise over, because we are not interested in but it appears as an important intermediate state.

We can write similar relationships in any orderings, such as $\mathbf{y} \rightarrow  \mathbf{u} \rightarrow \mathbf{f}$ or $\mathbf{u} \rightarrow  \mathbf{f} \rightarrow \mathbf{y}$, etc.